# How to generate only @HttpExchange and DTOs from OpenAPI spec?

Tags: spring, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I have an OpenAPI spec file, but I couldn't get the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin` generate only the Spring `@HttpExchange` interfaces and DTOs (model classes).

The closest I could get was using the [`spring` generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/) with `<library>spring-http-interface</library>` but it generates some stuff I don't want about client configuration and service wrapping.

The problems I have with this generated configuration is that it makes wrong assumptions on the REST client I want to use (I'm writing a servlet and intend to use `RestClient`, not `WebClient`). Plus I want to configure that REST client bean myself (tune authorization and proxy settings).

What I used so far:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
    <version>7.2.0</version>
    <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/../spec.json</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <apiPackage>com.my.service.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.my.service.model</modelPackage>
                <configOptions>
                   <library>spring-http-interface</library>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Did I miss a config option?

Is there another generator I can use to produce just the `@HttpExchange` interfaces and DTOs?